# ¿Cómo invoco un evento de un jTable desde código con una clase interna?

Tags: java, jtable

Quiero poder acceder desde un método a un evento del jTable como el cliked pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, necesito que me den un ejemplo de como puedo utilizar los eventos del jTable pero desde codigo

Comment: efrain, leíste bien el comentario en tu otra pregunta? Necesito el código donde instas tu JTable (algo como `JTable tablaCliente = new JTable();`)

Comment: no lo instancie

Comment: Eso no es posible. ;) en este caso te saldría una NPE en `tablaCliente.getModel()`. Busca donde defines esta variable en tu código y compartelo en tu otra pregunta. Si no lo encuentras, comparte el código entero de tu clase `Cotizar`.

Comment: siendo sincero, nunca lo instancie, tablaCliente es el nombre de la variable de mi jtable y despues obtuve el modelo  'DefaultTableModel ModeloClientes = (DefaultTableModel) tablaCliente.getModel();'

Comment: Te repito: no es posible que no instas la tabla (probablemente lo haces donde asignas la variable). Tu código nunca llegará a mostrar la tabla que tienes en tu imagen si no hubiera sido instado.